# Selectively disable XML Formatter in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET Web API, I need to force XML output for a single method but leave the JSON formatter enabled for others. Everything that I have seen on the topic has suggested removing the JSON formatter from the GlobalConfiguration as follows:

```cs
// remove JSON formatter
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
formatters.Remove(formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

This works but disables JSON output application wide. I need to be able to specify a formatter for a specific method or controller without affecting the global configuration. Is this possible or can it only be done via the GlobalConfiguration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft introduced [per-controller configuration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/05/11/per-controller-configuration-in-webapi/) for this specific purpose. You *will* need to split up your functionality into different controllers, but hopefully that will not be too much of a hassle for your specific goal (it might even be an improvement).

Basically, here is what you do:

1. Setup basic JSON formatting for the general case
2. Introduce a specific Controller for the XML methods, and give it a specific configuration:

---

```
[XMLControllerConfig]
public class XMLController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string SomeMethod(string someArgument)
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

...

```
class XMLControllerConfigAttribute: Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, 
                           HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Clear();
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(new XMLFormatter());
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly except that I needed to use a System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter instead of an XMLFormatter.